# How to edit code file Template custom page in Pages Wordpress

Tags: php, html, wordpress, custom-wordpress-pages

I need to do the function for directly editing the code file in Pages corresponding to the currently selected Template custom, which is similar to Wordpress Theme Editor function in 
`Wp-admin > Appearance > Theme Editor`

Ignore security and security issues because they can be edited directly. I don't know if this can be done.
The photo below is my desired idea.

[image]
Hope everyone help, thank you all!

Comment: You won't be able to edit the template file from within the editor because that will be placed where you call the_content(). My suggestion is to carry on using the editor purely as a content editor and look into something like Advanced Custom Fields to add extra customisable fields

Comment: @JonBennett thank you! I tried to use  Advanced Custom Fields to edit my arbitrary code, it works but now the code will save to the database, I don't want that, I want to edit the code directly into the PHP file so that I don't have to save the database